Issue with automatic Bundling in Field Service
I have an issue with the automatic bundling in FSL ! I set up to run the batch every day at 11 pm (for 5 different territories) ! For a specific territory, when then Bundle is created, if I run again the automatic bundling 24h later, then the Bundle is automatically unbundled then re-bundled ! I didn't change anything in the Setup and only one territory is concerned ! Have you ever encountered this kind of issue ?
